# Center text vertically in <a> tag

Tags: css

```
<a id="asapg" href="/link/">Text</a>

a#asapg {display: inline-block;cursor: pointer;padding: 15px;text-align: center;border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(121, 119, 119, 0.15);text-transform:uppercase;font-size:16px;width:100%;vertical-align: middle;background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);min-height: 170px;}
```

I am trying to vertically center the text in the middle for the  link but no luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `line-height` equal to the `height` of your element (170px?)

```
a#asapg{
   ...
   height: 170px;
   line-height: 170px;
}
```

Comment: It would not work indeed, you could use `display: table-cell ` and ` vertical-align: middle` in that case.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use flexbox, CSS3 feature.

```
 a#asapg {
    height: 170px;
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    align-items:center;/*Vertical align*/
    justify-content:center;/*horizontal align*/
  }
```

Comment: The browser support information in the comments there is hideously out of date. It looks like you just copy/pasted a bunch of that from this [7-year-old article](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/).

Comment: Should those be left out?